# RestKit - Unable to find parser for MIMEType 'text/html'

Tags: xml, mime-types, restkit

I am currently new to using RestKit for IOS and had an issue. I had setup a JAXRS service call that retrieves data from the backend and displays the content in xml. So you would have a url like http://www.example.com/service/clients. This would return the list of clients etc.
I am trying to use the RestKit Framework in IOS to map the xml into an object I can use. Does anyone know of a simple example that does this. Below is the majority of the code I am using:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
{
  RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://www.example.com/service"];
RKObjectMapping *clientMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[client class]];
[clientMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastName" toAttribute:@"lastName"];
[clientMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];

[manager.mappingProvider setMapping:hcpMapping forKeyPath:@/clients"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/clients" delegate:self];
.....
}
```

I am receiving the following error for the above:
HTTP Status 406 - No match for accept header
restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:241 Unable to find parser for MIMEType 'text/html'

this seems to be an error being returned from the page however, I am able to run the page and it returns xml with no problem from the browser. Does anyone know what I could have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class]
                           forMIMEType:@"text/html"];
```

This should do the trick. For some more details, please check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19604246/590525)** link.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying XML:

```
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeXML;
```