# why is RestKit changing my response content-type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

In short: I try to fetch data form the server with the `content-type` of the http request header set as `@"text/html`.. but for some reason RestKit changes that to `application/JSON`

**Explanation:**
If I were to make this request using just [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).. things work like a charm.. this is what my AFNetworking code looks like:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
                                               [NSURL URLWithString:kApiBaseUrl]];
singleton.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
[singleton setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/html"];
[client getPath:getPath parameters:nil success:successCallback failure:failureCallback];
```

If I use that *exact same client* and attach it to

```
MyClient *client = [MyClient getSingleton];  //MyClient is instantiated as above        
self.objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
self.objectManager.managedObjectStore = self.managedObjectStore;
// this should have already been done by my client, but putting
// it here just to be sure
[self.objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:@"text/html"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:kGradesPath 
                                       parameters:nil 
                                          success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
 // handle success
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 // handle failure
}];
```

the error i get is:

```
 restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: 
 Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error
 Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "application/json"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x8f7acd0
```

digging into the subject.. i put a break point in [managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/Network/RKObjectManager.m?source=c), then I checked the [acceptableContentTypes](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/Network/RKHTTPRequestOperation.h?source=c) of `HTTPRequestOperation` created, and it's nil! So i'm assuming that RestKit is just putting its own default acceptable content types.. i just don't know where and how to prevent it. ideas?

**p.s.** I don't have control over the server, so I can't change it's `content-type` header to `application/JSON`

---

**Update:**

It turns out that in [RKObjectRequestOperation.m](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/Network/RKObjectRequestOperation.m?source=c) it gets the `mime-type` from `[RKMIMETypeSerialization registeredMIMETypes];`(line 354).. and so in [RKMIMETypeSerialization.h](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Code/Support/RKMIMETypeSerialization.h?source=cc)there is the method:

```
/**
 Registers the given serialization class to handle content for the given MIME Type identifier.

 MIME Types may be given as either a string or as a regular expression that matches the MIME Types for which the given serialization should handle. Serializations are searched in the reverse order of their registration. If a registration is made for an already registered MIME Type, the new registration will take precedence.

 @param serializationClass The class conforming to the RKSerialization protocol to be registered as handling the given MIME Type.
 @param MIMETypeStringOrRegularExpression A string or regular expression specifying the MIME Type(s) that given serialization implementation is to be registered as handling.
 */
+ (void)registerClass:(Class<RKSerialization>)serializationClass forMIMEType:(id)MIMETypeStringOrRegularExpression;
```

how do I use this to register a `text/html` content-type?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

RestKit generally expects a single MIMEType (JSON) for its response data. However, you can tell it to handle other types like `text/plain` and `text/html` using the method you found and in my experience it's been pretty handy. Adding this to my RestKit config (which I do in my app delegate) allows me to accept both `application/json` and `text/html` as response data content-types.

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];
```

In my case, this is also helpful because Jersey - the web services framework the backend team at my company uses - defaults the content-type of empty payloads to `text/plain`, which triggers failure blocks unless I've specifically registered for that MIMEType.

Hope this helps.

Comment: could there be some [side effects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607672/restkit-property-mapping-quesiton) to the above?

Comment: Did not help in my case, i have new error:"Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'text/html'"

Comment: @VasyaVasyaa I've seen that before and it generally had to do with setting up my response descriptors and success codes correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I use change const value to type that recive from server api like this

```
NSString * const RKMIMETypeJSON = @"text/html";
```

if recived text structure same as JSON this approach works perfect