# RestKit text/html serialization issue

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking

In AFN 2.0 there is a property to set the content type and serialize the response. I used the following code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

But in Restkit, I cant serialize the response to text/html since they are using AFN 1.x and the code above works on 2.x. How can I solve this issue?

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
```

Comment: You should use serialization provided by RestKit itself: `[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];`

Comment: @Ad-J why didn't you add an answer?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603976/why-is-restkit-changing-my-response-content-type

Answer (score 1):

You should use serialization provided by RestKit itself: 
`[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];`